# It is possible to use bidirectional dependency in UML class diagram?

Tags: dependencies, uml, class-diagram, bidirectional-relation

I have 2 classes, they are more complex but that is not important..
How should I draw this dependency in UML class diagram ? I'm not sure how it should look like

```
public class A {
  private void foo(B b){
   ....
  }
  ...
}

public class B {
  private void foo(A a){
   ....
  }
   ....
}
```

could I draw something like this ? or how should it look like ? 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly ok. You can alternatively use a single bi-directional dependency.

[image]

P.S. From a design perspectice I don't think it's so ok. Having dependencies in both directions means your design should be revised. a A dependency *should* go only in one direction. Cross-dependencies are just a cause for trouble. See also [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency).

Comment: I have added the methods in the picture as in the OP's edited question (just see that my pic shows them public - guess that's ok ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you have Aggregation. See more details [here](http://bellekens.com/2010/12/20/uml-composition-vs-aggregation-vs-association/). But if it is really just dependency you can use the arrow the way did.

Comment: This can't be an aggregation since you can not construct two elements that aggregate each other. How would you construct elements that can only be constructed if the aggregated part was already existent?

Comment: @Thomas Kilian, it seemed a bit illogical to me in first place and decided to point this out. Otherwise you are correct. If it was composition it could have been bidirectional but bidirectional aggregation doesn't make sense.